# Animating a 2D array with changing colors using scatter (matplotlib)

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation, scatter-plot

I want to animate a 2D array (with fixed points), where the color of the points change. For other reasons I am using a class Individual which has a x-coordinate, a y-coordinate and a attribute color. My code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

N = 100

class Individual:
    def __init__(self, x_axis, y_axis, color):
        self.x_axis = x_axis
        self.y_axis = y_axis
        self.color = color

population = np.empty([N], dtype=Individual)

i = 0
while i < 10:
    population[i] = Individual(np.random.uniform(0, 1), np.random.uniform(0, 1), "red")
    i = i + 1

i = 10
while i < N:
    population[i] = Individual(np.random.uniform(0, 1), np.random.uniform(0, 1), "blue")
    i = i + 1

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
scat = ax.scatter([i.x_axis for i in population], [i.y_axis for i in population], 
                  c=[i.color for i in population])
ax.set_xlim((0, 1))
ax.set_ylim((0, 1))
ax.grid(b=True, which='major', color='k', linestyle='--')

def init():
    scat = ax.scatter([i.x_axis for i in population], [i.y_axis for i in population], 
                      c=[i.state for i in population])
    return scat,

def animate(i):
    for i in population:   # only exemplary update
        if i.state == 'red':
            i.state = 'blue'
        else:
            i.state = 'red'
    c = [i.state for i in population]
    scat.set_array(c) # this is supposed to update the colors
    return scat,

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(scat, animate, init_func=init, frames=200, 
                               interval=20, blit=True)
plt.show()
```

I get these error messages:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/benno/PycharmProjects/AnimationTests/Animation.py", line 50, in <module>
    anim = animation.FuncAnimation(scat, animate, init_func=init, frames=200, interval=20, blit=True)
  File "C:\Users\benno\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\animation.py", line 1696, in __init__
    TimedAnimation.__init__(self, fig, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\benno\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\animation.py", line 1433, in __init__
    event_source = fig.canvas.new_timer()
AttributeError: 'PathCollection' object has no attribute 'canvas'
```

Have I done anything fundamentally wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation.html) expects a [`matplotlib.figure.Figure`](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.figure.Figure.html) instance as the first positional argument, not a [`matplotlib.artist`](https://matplotlib.org/api/artist_api.html). In your code `scat` is an `artist`, `fig` is the `Figure` instance. The line

```py
anim = animation.FuncAnimation(scat, animate, init_func=init, frames=200, 
                               interval=20, blit=True)
```

should be

```py
anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init, frames=200, 
                               interval=20, blit=True)
```

Comment: Thank you, I still get an error which is (I think) because of the line ``` scat.set_array(c) ``` How do I give the colors saved in c to the function set_array() correctly?

Comment: @MATH101 You should be using [`set_color`](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.0/api/collections_api.html#matplotlib.collections.PathCollection.set_color) to set the colors.